# Includegraphics is not working

Tags: includegraphics

This is the template I am using to write a report.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\geometry{a4paper,total={170mm,257mm},left=10mm,right=15mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{simpler-wick}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cancel}
%\usepackage{MnSymbol,wasysym}
%\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
%----------------------------------------Frame--------------
\usepackage{framed} % or, "mdframed"
\usepackage[framed]{ntheorem}
\newframedtheorem{frm-thm}{Theorem}
%----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{simplewick}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{scalerel,amssymb}
\def\mcirc{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\circ}{j}}}
\def\msquare{\mathord{\scalerel*{\Box}{gX}}}
%--------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{2em}#1\hspace{2em}}}
\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}
\newcommand{\ba}{\begin{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\ea}{\end{eqnarray}}
\newcommand{\tr}{\mathrm{Tr}}
\newcommand{\D}{\int\mathcal{D}}
\newcommand{\bigzero}{\mbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries 0}}
\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\SumInt}{%
\mathchoice%
  {\ooalign{$\displaystyle\sum$\cr\hidewidth$\displaystyle\int$\hidewidth\cr}}
  {\ooalign{\raisebox{.14\height}{\scalebox{.7}{$\textstyle\sum$}}\cr\hidewidth$\textstyle\int$\hidewidth\cr}}
  {\ooalign{\raisebox{.2\height}{\scalebox{.6}{$\scriptstyle\sum$}}\cr$\scriptstyle\int$\cr}}
  {\ooalign{\raisebox{.2\height}{\scalebox{.6}{$\scriptstyle\sum$}}\cr$\scriptstyle\int$\cr}}
}
\title{}
\author{@.edu}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Whenever I am importing image files by `includegraphics` command, the. output is showing no images. Can anyone please help with this problem?

Comment: you have posted dozens of lines of code that do not use `\includegraphics` and have not shown any error message. You need to give some information about your problem

Comment: Note that you loaded the `cancel` package twice, the first time with no options, an the second time with the `makeroom` option, it can not be done. after removing the first call to the package it seems that images do appear when using `includegraphics`

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package cancel.`

Comment: add `\includegraphics{example-image}`  and it produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw0zN.png) so what is your question?